# Buttons on tkinter shrinking when assigning them images / python

Tags: python, image, button, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently working on a memmory/matching game, that consists on finding the spare cards on a matrix of buttons...

So the thing is that when you press a button, the button has to adquire an image, and put himself on a disabled mode untill the other button is pressed, and if it is a spare card, it has to stay like that.

My problem comes when clicking on the button and trying to give it an image. For some reason, when I give it an image, the button shrinks itself and then nothing more happens. And I really dont know why is this happening, because if I instead of giving it an image, just change its color, it works, and there is no shrink at all.

So heres the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import sys

def CargarImagenlvl1(nombre): #Define la funcion "global" que carga las imagenes necesarias
    ruta = os.path.join('Imagenes lvl1',nombre)
    imagen = PhotoImage(file=ruta)
    return imagen

#--------------------------------------------Imagenes----------------------------------------------------

def VentanaPlay():
    matriz = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    VentanaPlay= Tk()
    VentanaPlay.title("Focus Now!")
    VentanaPlay.resizable(width=NO, height=NO)
    VentanaPlay.geometry("800x600")

    CanvPlay= Canvas(VentanaPlay, width=800, height=600, bg="white")
    CanvPlay.config(cursor="dotbox")
    CanvPlay.place(x=-1,y=-1)

    CanvPlay1= Canvas(CanvPlay)
    CanvPlay1.config(bg="white")
    CanvPlay1.place(x=1,y=1)

    ABOUT=CargarImagenlvl1("About.gif")

    def Matriz():
        global Bot
        Bot=[] #Botones ([Numero de boton])
        ind=0 #Indicador para crear la cantidad de botones
        c1,c2=0,0 #Columnas y filas
        while ind < 49:
            Bot.append(Button(CanvPlay1,width=10,height=5,bg="#309090"))
            Bot[ind].grid(row=c2,column=c1)
            ind+=1
            if c1==6: c1,c2=0,c2+5
            else: c1+=1
        Bot[0].config(command=lambda: dele(0)), Bot[1].config(command=lambda: dele(1))
        Bot[2].config(command=lambda: dele(2)), Bot[3].config(command=lambda: dele(3))
        Bot[4].config(command=lambda: dele(4)), Bot[5].config(command=lambda: dele(5))
        Bot[6].config(command=lambda: dele(6)), Bot[7].config(command=lambda: dele(7))
        Bot[8].config(command=lambda: dele(8)), Bot[9].config(command=lambda: dele(9))
        Bot[10].config(command=lambda: dele(10)), Bot[11].config(command=lambda: dele(11))
        Bot[12].config(command=lambda: dele(12)), Bot[13].config(command=lambda: dele(13))
        Bot[14].config(command=lambda: dele(14)), Bot[15].config(command=lambda: dele(15))
        Bot[16].config(command=lambda: dele(16)), Bot[17].config(command=lambda: dele(17))
        Bot[18].config(command=lambda: dele(18)), Bot[19].config(command=lambda: dele(19))
        Bot[20].config(command=lambda: dele(20)), Bot[21].config(command=lambda: dele(21))
        Bot[22].config(command=lambda: dele(22)), Bot[23].config(command=lambda: dele(23))
        Bot[24].config(command=lambda: dele(24)), Bot[25].config(command=lambda: dele(25))
        Bot[26].config(command=lambda: dele(26)), Bot[27].config(command=lambda: dele(27))
        Bot[28].config(command=lambda: dele(28)), Bot[29].config(command=lambda: dele(29))
        Bot[30].config(command=lambda: dele(30)), Bot[31].config(command=lambda: dele(31))
        Bot[32].config(command=lambda: dele(32)), Bot[33].config(command=lambda: dele(33))
        Bot[34].config(command=lambda: dele(34)), Bot[35].config(command=lambda: dele(35))
        Bot[36].config(command=lambda: dele(36)), Bot[37].config(command=lambda: dele(37))
        Bot[38].config(command=lambda: dele(38)), Bot[39].config(command=lambda: dele(39))
        Bot[40].config(command=lambda: dele(40)), Bot[41].config(command=lambda: dele(41))
        Bot[42].config(command=lambda: dele(42)), Bot[43].config(command=lambda: dele(43))
        Bot[44].config(command=lambda: dele(44)), Bot[45].config(command=lambda: dele(45))
        Bot[46].config(command=lambda: dele(46)), Bot[47].config(command=lambda: dele(47))
        Bot[48].config(command=lambda: dele(48))

    def dele(coordenada):
        if matriz[coordenada]==0:
            matriz[coordenada]=1
            Bot[coordenada].config(state=DISABLED, height=5, width=10,image=ABOUT) #Here I assign the image, wich is the part that makes the buttons shrink.

    Matriz()

    VentanaPlay.mainloop()

VentanaPlay()
```

Here's a screenshot of what is happening:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrCLB.png
[image: sscreenshot]

Buttons are shrinking, though I think the image is showing but on a very little size, and BTW I have made sure that the resolution of the image was exactly the same as the squares, I even tried putting images way bigger, but still the same.

Hope you can help me out here! Thanks!
PD: Excuse my awful eng skills.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709154/displaying-square-tkinter-buttons both caused by button's units when displaying image and text.

Answer (score 0):

When adding images onto tkinter buttons, each button which has an image on top will change so that the button's width and height will be stated in pixels, instead of the units that the button widget defaults to without an image on top.

You wrote:

`Bot[coordenada].config(state=DISABLED, height=5, width=10,image=ABOUT)`

Since an image has been added, the height and width are now in pixels. But all the other buttons remain their larger size because they do not have an image on top.

Hope this helped! Here's a link...
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when developing on a similar project.  In my case I was able to find a workaround by specifying the grid layout on the main window using rowconfigure and columnconfigure and the minsize option.

example below.  Not elegant worked out for my particular issue.

```
root = ttk.Tk()
root.title("Matchgame")
for x in range(4):
    root.rowconfigure(x,minsize=220, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(x,minsize=220, weight=1)
```

This prevented the underlying columns and rows from shrinking even if all of the images were displayed in a particular row or column.