# Why are my tkinter buttons not the width I specify?

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter

so I have this working application so far:

```
import tkinter as tk

class AppGui(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Set window size
        self.geometry("400x600")

        # Create main container frame
        self.cframe = tk.Frame(self,
            bg = "yellow",
            width  = 400,
            height = 600
        )
        self.cframe.place(x=0,y=0)

        # Draw the first page and move on
        self.Draw()

    def Draw(self):
        # Create top bar and label
        topbar = tk.Frame(self.cframe,bg="green",width=400,height=60)
        topbar.place(x=0,y=0)

        l = tk.Label(topbar,
            text = "TOP Title",
            bg   = "red"
        )
        l.place(x=200,y=30,anchor="center")


        # Create center container
        centerpanel = tk.Frame(self.cframe,bg="orange",width=400,height=480)
        centerpanel.place(x=0,y=60)

        # Create a one-pixel image
        pixel = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)

        # Create program select button group
        b_left = tk.Button(centerpanel,
            text   = "Left",
            image  = pixel, # This allows me to specify width in pixels.
            width  = 75,
            height = 50,
            compound = "c"
        )
        b_left.place(x=25,y=30)

        b_center = tk.Button(centerpanel,
            text   = "Center",
            image  = pixel, # This allows me to specify width in pixels.
            width  = 75,
            height = 50,
            compound = "c"
        )
        b_center.place(x=150,y=30)

        b_right = tk.Button(centerpanel,
            text   = "Right",
            image  = pixel, # This allows me to specify width in pixels.
            width  = 75,
            height = 50,
            compound = "c"
        )
        b_right.place(x=275,y=30)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui = AppGui()
    gui.mainloop()
```

Basically what I wanted to get was a topbar with a label, a center panel with three buttons side by side (with some padding) and a bottom bar, which I have yet to implement.

I made every component a different color, and with that I have what I need to move on.

Howeber, to get that working, I had to set all the buttons *width* property to 75 pixels, so to get them to display as 100 pixels wide buttons (measured with screenruler).

This GUI is only going to run on a fixed hardware, so I'd like to keep using the *place* manager to put stuff on the window, if possible.

So, to sum it up: why are my buttons 25 pixels wider than the width I set them to?

Using Python 3 on Ubuntu 18.04 in case that's significant.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried putting each of the buttons in there own frame yet? I was look at this post, [Displaying square Tkinter.Button's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709154/displaying-square-tkinter-buttons) and it says that once you put the buttons in a frame so this way it treats the buttons as images and uses pixels instead of text sizes

Comment: Hi, @B.Cratty. I know there are workarounds to this, and thank you for the link, that also solves the "situation" with compound buttons. My question is more of a "why does this happen", rather than "how do I fix this" (I believe that's also the reason why you refrained from answering it in the first place?). Still, thank you for the link.

Comment: You're welcome and sorry I couldn't be much of help. The only thing I was able to find to help answer your post was in the link that I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final width of the button takes into account not only the specified width, but also any padding that may be set on the button. Since you're relying on the default value of the padding, it's probably non-zero. Add `padx=0` to see how that affects your button (eg: `b_right = tk.Button(..., width=100, padx=0)`.

Another option is to use `place` to force the size of the widget. Just add a `width` and `height` when calling place (eg: `b_right.place(x=275,y=30, width=100)` and it will override the settings of the button.

Comment: Ha, it really was the padding after all... Were you able to find any documentation, even non official, about this, by any chance?

Comment: @Guerriky: there's no documentation that specifically spells out that padding applies to the width. All it takes is a little experimentation by looking at all of the options, finding the ones that are related to size, changing the values, and seeing what happens.